# How do I create a condition to test if the value of a field is unchanged?

Tags: rules, 9

In Drupal 7 Rules I could create a condition "Data Value is Empty" and could drill down in the data selector to node-unchanged.field_to_test.

However in Drupal 9 Rules when I create a condition "Data Value is Empty" and drill down in the data selector "node_unchanged." does not display the node's fields to select.

I have created a condition "entity is of bundle" successfully and the node's fields display in a "Data Comparison" condition but not in a "Data Value is Empty" condition.

So my basic question is how to create a Rules condition to display and test that a field's value has not changed?

Answer (score 0):

In Rules

Select Condition: Entity is of bundle

entity: node_unchanged

type:node_unchanged

bundle: "machine name of content type"